# (CakePHP) Change Select Options in Form Based On Associated Table

Tags: forms, cakephp-3.0

I have a database with Users and Committees, each user has one committee and a committee has several users. In the 'add' panel of Users a committee should be selected. This was done by setting a list of committees in the controller and adding the following to the form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('committee_id', ['options' => $committees]);
```

This works, but the only problem is that the select options look as follows:

> {"id": 1, "name": "Main", "email": ...}

Instead of just the name of each committee.

Is there any way of changing the value of each select option to just the name?

Comment: how do you get the $committes. Did you call `find('list')`?

Comment: You are right! I used `find('all')`, changing it to `find('list')` solved it.